# VBA Data Validation - Selection Issue

Tags: excel, vba

In advance, sorry for my broken english.
I've been strugguling with this and I need some help. I'm using a validation code coming from the code of the Worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then

 'I've some code here just to filter the list to display

 With Target.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=blah
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
End With
End If
```

The problem is whenever i do a selection in the worksheet, for example: from K to T, im "passing" throught M so the code/validation will apply to the whole selection. I just want to apply ONLY if I click on M2, M3 and so.

i'll appreciate any help!

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, you are given `Target` and you should make use of it instead of `ActiveCell`.

Secondly, to skip for any targets which are in Row "M" . and in order to count for all eventualities, you must do to checks

- range to be changed is only 1 column wide
- column of range is "M"

This could be done with:

```
If Not (Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 13) Then
    MsgBox "Co-cooo"
End If
```

Comment: I never thought about that! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
With Target.Validation
```

with:

```
With Intersect(Target, Range("M:M"))
```